# Replace value of a $scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [angular-youtube-embed](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed) to show movie trailers in my Angular application.

I have to set a $scope called `theBestVideo` with that youtube link value,

```
$scope.theBestVideo = 'Lm8p5rlrSkY';
console.log ($scope.theBestVideo)
```

And then I display the trailer in my template like so,

```
%youtube-video{"video-id" => "theBestVideo"}
```

The problem here is ofcourse that every movie has the same template, since the value is set in the controller.

I do have the values of other trailers in my database that I also render on the same template as the youtube player,

```
%ul.trailers
  %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id}"}
    {{ trailer.link }}
```

So my question is, can I inject the value of `{{ trailer.link }}` into the scope '$scope.theBestVideo` in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the video template appear inside the ng-repeat?

So for instance you will have:

```
<div ng-repeat="trailer in trailers">
    <youtube-video video-id={{trailer.link}}" />
</div>
```

The main question is how do you trigger showing a specific trailer.
If you have a list of trailer, then what I suggested will work.

If the ng-repeat appears in a different part of the template, so you will have a list of trailers (without showing the video), and the video gets shown when you click it in the list - just bind the ng-click event to changing the videoUrl